# Cryptic clue: Boil rocks in wood scrap (7)

Tags: crosswords, cryptic-clues, crossword-clues

I'm newbie to cryptic crosswords and I'm a bit lost as to how "abolish" is the answer to the clue "Boil rocks in wood scrap (7)."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'Boil rocks' means 'an anagram of boil' ('boil' that's been kind of jolted around).

'Wood scrap' (noun) is what you get once you've burnt some wood: 'ash' 
(or maybe the author just intends 'wood', by itself, to mean 'ash' the species of tree - see comments below).

'In' means 'in the middle of'.

So it's an anagram of 'boil', in the middle of the word 'ash'.

> a-boli-sh

'Scrap' (verb) is the whole thing (to 'abolish' is to 'scrap').

Comment: AE, you beat me to it. The only thing I'd change is that you're thinking of the wrong kind of ash. _Scrap_ is in the literal part only. _Ash_ is meant as a kind of wood, not burnt wood. The OP may find the list of anagram indicators (anagrinds) [here](http://www.crosswordunclued.com/2008/09/anagram-indicators.html) to be of some interest.

Comment: @h34, yeah, I thought about that. It could be interpreted either way, because 'ash' is both a kind of wood and the scrap that wood turns into once you've burnt it. So I'm finding it hard to tell the author's intention. Presumably if you burn ash-wood then you get ash ash. ;)

Comment: Yes OK, an overlap between literal and cryptic parts is possible, if quite rare.

Comment: "Scrap is in the literal part only. Ash is meant as a kind of wood, not burnt wood" Yeah, I agree with this